# iPad html elements not appearing - until user interaction

Tags: ipad, user-interaction

I'm having a problem with some text and images not loading on the page when using an iPad, 2 and 3.  It's quite a random, intermittent problem but normally seems to effect the same sort of items.  I can't see what is different or special about those items.  The text that has this error uses an embedded font, but other text on the page does render using the same font, so it doesn't appear to be that the font embed has failed.  The images that error are in a carousel, and seem to appear once you start to swipe it.  So it seems to only show once the user has interacted with it.  Only person I could find having a similar problem, said that for them it was only elements that weren't on the first viewable page before scrolling, whereas for me some of the elements are "above the fold" too.  Their fix was to add -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) to the elements but that hasn't helped me.  Anyone know why this is happening and what a fix may be?  Unfortunately I cannot reveal the site in question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When loading this page, are you loading it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear? Try using viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: Sorry sorry, should have said, this is not an app, just a responsive web page designed to work on desktop, tablet and mobile.